# Redis notifications with lists

Tags: php, notifications, redis

I am building a website using Redis as queue/messaging store.

What I am trying to build now is a very *basic* notification system; What I am doing right now is the following:

```
//sending notification:
$idIn = idToSendNotificationTo();
$r->rpush("$idIn*notifs", "$myId*likephoto947574")
```

Considering that on a synchronous system such as PHP, pub/sub is not exactly viable, would this approach still work?

Also, how can I have the receiving user get all the notifications using lists? LPOP gets them one by one and, when the user opens up the webpage, all of the new notifications should popup.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you delivering notifications to clients? Are you listing KEYS in a loop or probing all possible keys every second?

Comment: As for the lists, you can use combination of LRANGE + LTRIM / DEL

Comment: I am delivering the notifications via an ajax call to a script every x seconds, like this: `LINDEX("$myId*notifs", 0);` or, well, whatver might be useful, like LRANGE + LTRIM

Comment: so what I could do is basically grab the notifications, say, 10 at a time and then trim them?

Comment: Yeah, use LRANGE+LTRIM. However, I'd deploy a separate solution for notifications and use pub/sub. Something with evented I/O. Node.js, or EventMachine or Twisted

Comment: +1 to the LRANGE + LTRIM approach. You'll probably need a counter aswell to track how many to pull and how many to trim, but otherwise it should do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I know it should be better to have it all more real time, but do you think that would *also* improve the performance greatly? if there is only little gain then, I would prefer sticking to PHP as honestly I am not really practical with node or similar. By the way if you write your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @johnsmith: stick with php then. I personally feel that it is too heavy for this kind of tasks. I mean, having to instantiate an interpreter, parse http request and call redis only to find out that there's nothing to show. Multiply that by the number of online customers and do it every second.

Comment: I remember, before knowing about Redis, I was using MongoDB for a chat system, moreover on PHP! I really can consider myself a *bad junior* programmer but that chat was going real fast, using a similar approach to this one, with 1000 concurrent users totally didn't break a sweat! I found that kind of weird, knowing about nodejs performance. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this approach can certainly work. To pop multiple items from a list, you should use a combination of [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) + [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim).